# coldFusion Session is undefined when in a virtual directory

Tags: iis, coldfusion

I have a one line page testSession.cfm. The one line is `<cfdump var="#session#" />`

I get the error :

```
 Variable SESSION is undefined.

The error occurred in E:\folder1\testSession.cfm: line 1

1 :     <cfdump var="#session#" />
```

The kicker is the testSession.cfm is in a virtual directory.  There are no other files in the virtual directory so the application.cfc from the root SHOULD be getting seen as the application.  Currently the entire application.cfc is

```
<cfcomponent output="false">
    <cfscript>
        THIS.name = 'testingstuff';
        THIS.SessionManagement = "Yes";
        THIS.SessionTimeout = CreateTimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 3);
        THIS.ApplicationTimeout = CreateTimeSpan(0, 8, 0, 0);
    </cfscript>
</cfcomponent>
```

I am sure I have had this working before in a virtual directory and I AM able to getting working on a railo box but NOT on a box running ACF 8 and IIS6 or IIS7.

I DO have a CF mapping set up (both on the working railo and the non-working CF8 boxes)

I feel confident that I am missing a setting somewhere but I do not know if it is IIS or CF related. I have gone through each setting in IIS on both CF and Railo they are the same but of course railo is also using Tomcat which isn't on the CF box so that could be a difference.

What might I have over looked?

Comment: Is the virtual dir in IIS? For example root being E:\folder2 and the vdir "folder1" being E:\folder1? You do not need a CF mapping and that may also be the root of your issue.

Comment: Yes, folder1 is the virtual directory.  We have tried both with and without the CF mapping , same result both ways

Comment: Is there an Application.cfc (or .cfm) in the virtual directory? If so, does it have a different application name?

Comment: Is it a timing issue? You have your session set to timeout after 3 seconds. Maybe try giving it longer. Does the session work under your web root?

Comment: Can you dump out `GetBaseTemplatePath()` as the 1st line in your testSession.cfm and see what it says.

Comment: @ScottStroz No there is no application.cfc (or cfm) in the virtual directory.  @Miguel-F I was playing with the timeout to see if that had an effect and No, it doesn't.  @John Whish it says `E:\folder1\testSession.cfm `

Comment: I found this article https://forums.adobe.com/thread/854781 and It appears that the "ApplicationProxy" method DOES work.  It seems clumsy and like it shouldn't be needed but it works